# UIImageView on rotating changes it width and height, how to get original height and width of normal state?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have an image of **width 200** and **height 200**.when I **rotate it** to some degree say **60** degree then **new width and height** comes out to be **273,273**.

But I **want to retrieve** the same **height and width 200*200** whatever rotation it has.

I am trying to scale that image to some ratio of back view size on which that image is placed. If back view reduces to half the image size is also reduced to half and same way if back view is increased to double image also increased to double. But when I rotate the image and try to change the frame of back view that image resizing works fine if it’s not rotated but if it’s rotated then resizing of back view ratio will not work fine with image ratio. Image either increase more or decrease. Generally it increases more than expected.

Comment: Have u used auto resize mask?

Comment: How are you rotating the image ? Provide some code.... If you are using gestures then there may be an issue but normal rotation does not change the dimensions of the image....

Comment: what auto resize mask will do ?i am using imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle) to transform.

Answer (score 1):

`view.bounds.size` would not change after the rotation

Answer (score 0):

Image.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle); works perfectly fine . Check your image .... if it is in ping or jpeg etc. The issue is with the image I think not with the method .. :)

Comment: this method is working perfectly fine .My problem is, when i put NSLog and print the height and width of imageView it is different after rotating.